# Svelte / Vanilla JS - do I need to use .then() on awaiting an async function?

Tags: javascript, svelte

This is probably best explained with code:

in my utils file I have created the following async function:

```
export async function post(fetch, url, body) {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body,
        headers
    });
    return await res.json();
}
```

I've stripped down the function to avoid posting too much code.

Now in my .svelte component file, the function above is called as followed:

```
async function handleLogin() {
    const result = await post(fetch, 'https://accountingserver.dev/auth/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
    });
    console.log(result);
}
```

In the above example, the result is output correctly as expected.  But I have found I can also do the following and get the same outcome:

```
async function handleLogin() {
    post(fetch, 'https://accountingserver.dev/auth/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

So my question, is any of the two methods more valid and if so .. why?

Comment: they're both perfectly valid. Async/await is essentially just a syntactic sugar for working with promises and `.then` anyway

Comment: Thanks, async / await  syntax looks strange to me as it's not clear if the code  after the await call is executed only after the result has arrived.  Is it safe assume console.log(result) will always have the data from the server when using await?

Comment: the whole *point* of async/await is that the `await` keyword makes it clear that the code is "waiting" for the promise to resolve before getting its value. So yes, it's safe to assume that.

Comment: Thanks, that has answered my question

Comment: In your second example `function handleLogin()` doesn't need async in front of it, since you arent returning a promise or using `await` inside of it.

Comment: @Spankied of course, thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a preference thing, but where possible you should lean towards using `async/await`. It makes your code cleaner and easier to read and also helps you avoid [Promise Hell](https://www.google.com/search?q=promise%20hell&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS903US912&oq=promise%20h&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0i512l2j46i20i175i199i263i512j69i60l3.1181j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

You should note that some environments might not support `async/await` as it is a newer feature, but most modern environments will likely natively support it. In cases where `async/await` is not supported, `async function name(){}` syntax will not be allowed and you will need to use `.then()` instead of `await`.

Comment: I think with the exception of IE11, all browsers today support async/await... so any worries about async support is mostly irrelevant nowadays.